# Which zfs command/systemd unit to depend on to ensure that a mountpoint is available?

Tags: mount, services, systemd, zfs

I would like to make sure that a ZFS mountpoint is available before service managed by `systemd` starts. Therefore I'd use the `After=` stanza in the `systemd` unit. But, what to write as argument?

I'm using a local installation of ZFS because of ongoing performance issues with the shipped version and import the only pool with

```
[Unit]
Description=ZFS pool import for source installations of ZFS
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/zpool import -d /dev data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

because I never found any useful documentation of `systemd` support on Ubuntu and it [seems to be targeted by devs only now](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/pull/6548).

However, on another system I also experience trouble with the built-in resources, e.g. `zfs-mount.service` is loaded and running even if no pools are imported and thus no mounts could have been successful.

Is there a target that I can make my services depend on in order to start only after the mountpoint is available and refuse to start if the whole ZFS or just the mountpoint failed to initialize (and that I could copy for my local installation)?

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### System Defaults

There is a lot of magic here, but on Ubuntu 18.04 the answer *generally* seems to be `zfs.target`, which is listed as `WantedBy` all of the various `zfs-*.service`s (mount, modprobe, etc.). You will see this if you peruse through

```
more /lib/systemd/system/zfs* | less
```

You may notice that there is also a `zfs-import.target` which is satisfied after `zpool import` has run, but before filesystems are mounted.

In my case, though, there are other steps that need to happen first (encrypted block device mapping, for example) so these will not work out of the box for me.

#### Specific Mount Points

For specific mount points I would recommend not relying on the general `zfs.target`, but rather add your own service (perhaps with `Wants=zfs.target`) that checks the status of the specific mounts your system relies upon. For example, if you rely on `/blah/my/zfs/mount` being mounted, just create a service for that which can check the zfs mount status before returning, perhaps with

```
zfs get mounted blah/my/zfs/mount | grep yes
```

#### Example

`/etc/systemd/system/my-zfs-mount.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=ZFS mount blah/my/zfs/mount
Wants=zfs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/sbin/zfs get mounted blah/my/zfs/mount | grep yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then your other services can depend on this one.

Comment: Strange that there's no easier way to do this which would spare the extra unit.

Comment: A dependency on `zfs.target`, `zfs-import.target` isn't deterministic enough for my taste (they succeed, no matter whether the pool was imported or not), therefore I created a `Requires=zfs-pool-import-poolname.service` dependency, changed the `Type` to `simple` and am polling the availability with `Restart=on-failure RestartSec=5`. The zpool availability check is performed with `zpool status`.